# Autoit read html on browser close

Tags: autoit

FYI, I'm a newbie to Autoit...I can successfully read some div content from IE using autoit, but I can only read it when the page loads.  I'm wanting to read it as the page closes to get the latest information.  I have some javascript that changes div content when on the page, then I want to dump that info to use elsewhere.

```
$oIE = _IECreate("\\developnow\Local Files\HTML5\Test Form 1.html#docid=144_721=Test Form 1")
$divs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "div")

For $div In $divs
    If $div.className == "bigString" Then
       $divContent = $div.innerText
    EndIf
```

How do I get the `innerText` of `bigString` as the page is closing, rather than as the page is loading? Or maybe get the info only when `bigString` changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple AdlibRegister solution:

```
#include <IE.au3>

_IEErrorHandlerRegister()
Global $oIE = _IECreate("\\developnow\Local Files\HTML5\Test Form 1.html#docid=144_721=Test Form 1")
Global $LatestText = ""
$OldText = ""

AdlibRegister("_IEGetElementText")

While True
    If $OldText <> $LatestText Then
        $OldText = $LatestText
        ConsoleWrite($LatestText & @LF)
    EndIf
WEnd



Func _IEGetElementText()

        $divs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "div")

        For $div In $divs
            If ($div.className == "bigString") And ($div.innerText <> "") Then
               $LatestText = $div.innerText
           EndIf
       Next

EndFunc
```